# precision recall curve is like stairs

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, ensemble-modeling

I am training an ensemble model using a 400 data set sample this led to a precision recall curve that looks like stairs ? what would be the reason beside the low number of samples ?

Comment: please reformulate your questions clearly, indicating what you want to be answered

Answer (score 1):

A precision-recall curve (as well as a ROC curve) is made from the different thresholds which can be used to separate predictions between positive and negative instances. These thresholds naturally depend on the possible values predicted by the classifier.

For example, if the classifier predicts only 3 different values $a<b<c$, then the threshold $t$ can only be in these positions:

- $t<a$
- $a<t<b$
- $b<t<c$
- $c<t$

Each of these positions will correspond to one pair of values for precision and recall, so exactly one point in the curve. Therefore the shape of the curve (how smooth it is) depends on how many *different* values the classifier predicts.

Thus a stairs-shaped curve shows that the classifier predicts only a few different values. There can be various reasons for that, but since you mention ensemble learning I guess that the final predicted value is based on the proportion of individual learners predicting the positive class, right? If yes that would explain it: if there are $N$ individual learners then the final predicted value can only be $0,1/N,2/N,...,N$. This means a maximum of $N+1$ different values and therefore a maximum of $N+1$ points on the curve.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but in fact, I am comparing ensemble methods with single classifiers and both courses of precision-recall for both classifiers are stairs shaped so maybe the re would be another reason linked to the data itself

Comment: I didn't understand where the ensemble method happens but it doesn't matter. What you could do first is to plot the distributions of the predicted values/probabilities, I would expect a kind of discrete distribution with only a few different values.

Comment: ok here is the full story I am using a stacking ensemble method and I am comparing stacking performances with the single classifiers that compose this stacking model (when they are trained independently form this model) and I get precision-recall curves this way

Comment: @ou2105 You're using the predicted *probability* (not the predicted *class*) to build the PR curve, right? And how are the output from the singles classifiers combined in the meta-model?

Comment: Yes I am using probabilities instead of the predicted classes Erwan

Comment: @ou2105 did you look at the distribution of the predicted probabilities?

Comment: I did it and I noticed even taught individual classifiers are not good in separating the 2 classes, (0 and 1) you can see that stacking classifier is better in separating them

Comment: @ou2105 ok but are there many different values? f there is a strong stairs effect on the PR curve it must come from a low number of points (P,R), and this usually happens because the underlying probabilities are not continuous.

Comment: the classifiers are KNN, DEcision tree and svm so no much variety in KNN , Decision tree is discrete also, and the SVM , performers in and way for this data set